# How can I set an environment variable permanently in CentOS?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, environment-variables

I used a following commmand in SSH terminal on my server:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
```

and it works fine: my program finds all libraries at this point (if I launch it from my SSH command line).

A command

```
env
```

shows that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set properly.

But! When I close my SSH client and reconnect again there is no LD_LIBRARY_PATH set any more.

How to set environment variables constantly on my server under CentOS? Thanks.

Comment: Solution: you should create a file .sh in /etc/profile.d with export command

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in your own answer and the one given by @Fegnoid,  exporting the variables in a `.sh` file inside `/etc/profile.d/` or in `~/.bash_profile` would do the trick. Keep in mind that if you intend to use these environment variables in a service script, it might not work as you expect since `service` purges all environment variables except a few.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44378/148497.

Answer (score 2):

Export the variables in the ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile of the user to have them set on login so the line would be

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: But it is the same command that I used. It gives no effect after reconnect.

Comment: did you enter the line into the above files i listed? and saved them

Comment: Yes, but I don't find this variable. Should I reboot server? Alternatively, I created .sh in /etc/profile.d with this command and it worked!

Comment: yeah that would, but it will put it in effect for every user, i actually got what you need to enter wrong and have corrected my answer - sorry